# UITableView content not displayed the very first time even after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create an account page where user will be able to select his preferable language and voice. For this part of my app I was thinking to create 2 different UIButtons and once user has press one of them, a UITableView will appear on appropriate location `tableFrame` (something like drop down menu). Things were working great, initially, when I had just one array. Now, I have a general array that used from Table View delegate methods to load data and 2 other arrays that contain languages and voices.

My problem is that the very first time when I am tapping on any of the buttons, the table displays no content but `numberOfRowsInSection` returns correct value. Next, if tap on the same or the other button again .. everything is fine.

I believe the problem appears where I am, initially, initialise the general array with no object in `viewDidLoad`.

I have tried `reloadData` with now success.

Any ideas? Below my code:

Account.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AccountViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{

    NSMutableArray *content;
    NSMutableArray *languages;
    NSMutableArray *voices;

    CGRect tableFrame;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *languageBtn;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *narratorBtn;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *contentTbl;

- (IBAction)selectLanguage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)selectVoice:(id)sender;

@end
```

Account.m

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad{

        [super viewDidLoad];

        content = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        languages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"English", @"Ελληνικά", @"French", @"Spanish", @"Deutch", nil];
        voices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"English", @"US English", @"Ελληνικά", @"Spanish", nil];

    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [content count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }


    - (IBAction)selectLanguage:(id)sender{

        if ([(UIButton *)sender tag] == 0) {
            content = [languages copy];

            tableFrame = CGRectMake(50, 173, 220, 203);
            [self startAnimationAndDisplayTable:YES];
            [(UIButton *)sender setTag:1];
        } else{
            [self startAnimationAndDisplayTable:NO];
            [(UIButton *)sender setTag:0];
        }
    }

    - (IBAction)selectVoice:(id)sender{

        if ([(UIButton *)sender tag] == 0) {
            content = [voices copy];

            tableFrame = CGRectMake(50, 243, 220, 203);
            [self startAnimationAndDisplayTable:YES];
            [(UIButton *)sender setTag:1];
        } else{
            [self startAnimationAndDisplayTable:NO];
            [(UIButton *)sender setTag:0];
        }

    }

- (void)startAnimationAndDisplayTable:(BOOL)show{

    if (show) {
        [self.contentTbl setHidden:NO];
        [self.contentTbl setFrame:tableFrame];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Fade In" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
        [self.contentTbl setAlpha:1.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.contentTbl reloadData];
    } else{
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Fade Out" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [self.contentTbl setAlpha:0.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

"`content`" is an empty mutable array until you touch whatever (button?) action that calls the "`selectLanguage`" and "`selectVoice`" methods (and then you reassign the "`content`" variable).

I don't see any other manipulations of the "`content`" mutable array, so it's no wonder to me that nothing appears until you actually touch something.

You also do not show *where* you are calling "`reloadData`".  "`content`" needs to have array entries in there for "`reloadData`" to work.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I've missed the last method, where `reloadData` appears. I will update my question... I am changing `content`'s values once user has tap a button and then calling `reloadData` inside `startAnimationAndDisplayTable`. Using this technique because I don't know how to pass different array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method in runtime (I don't know if this is possible, too).